# Get the position of a ListView item that was just created?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, int

In my winform I create an item in a listview like so;

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.Add("an item");
```

How can I get its <s>position</s> index? I've tried the following;

```
int position = item.Position;
int position = item.SelectedIndices[0];
```

But neither works.

I would use `listView1.SelectedIndices[0];` but the newly created item isn't selected so that won't work either.

EDIT: By position, I meant the index of the item, not its co-ordinates. Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add` methods all return a `ListViewItem` object. The `ListViewItem` object has an `Index` property that will return the zero-based index of the item within the ListView control.

The `Position` method does something else entirely. It returns the *coordinates* of the ListViewItem's top-left corner. These coordinates are relative to the ListView control.

Comment: so I should use `item.Index` ?

Comment: If you want the index, yes.